# Bounding this integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, summation

I'm trying to get a  lower bound for $$\int_0^{\pi n} \left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|dx$$ and if I can show that it's greater than $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k\pi}\int_0^\pi\sin x\, dx$$ then I can conclude what I want. What confuses me is the denominator. This is likely very simple and I am missing something "obvious."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace the denominator with something bigger, then you get something smaller (since everything in your problem is positive).

So for instance, you could replace $x$ with $k \pi$ whenever $(k-1) \pi \leq x \leq k \pi$, for $k=1,2,\dots,n$. Then you get a lower bound of

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{k \pi}^{(k+1) \pi} \frac{|\sin(x)|}{k \pi} dx = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k \pi} \int_0^\pi \sin(x) dx.$$

In the last step, we exploit the fact that the integral of sine over the upper semicircle has the same magnitude as the integral over the lower semicircle.